# How to park vehicles of random size on a 2d board?

Tags: javascript

**Problem**: I've a 2d board (HTML canvas or div) and some vehicles (png images) of different size. I've to place /park vehicle on the board randomly. They should not intersect.

- Every vehicle can be rotated by any angle.
- Every vehicle can be resized by X% of it's original size.

What I can think for it's algorithm is

1. Check if all n vehicles can be parked in available area
2. if yes, mark random area for vehicle 1

   1. Check if all n-1 vehicles can be parked in available area
   2. if yes then reserve marked area. and go to step 1 with n -1 vehicle.
   3. if no then go to step 2
3. if no, resize a random vehicle and go to step 1

**challenge**: how to know optimally if all given vehicles can fit in given space.

I can know the boundary of vehicle image with the help of HTML canvas. 
I need help to write an algorithm of parking vehicles on the board.

Comment: This sounds a bit like sprite packing - have you researched packing algorithms to find some leads?

Comment: not yet, let me google